# Calling a TypeScript function from a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, referenceerror

On the file `app-component.html` there is a button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="confirmChanges()">Save Changes</button>
```

This `confirmChanges` calls a javascript function located on my `index.html` file:

```
<script>
    function confirmChanges(){
      var optionSelected = confirm('Are you sure?');
      if(optionSelected == true){
        alert('Changes were applied sucessfully!');
        updateAddress();
      } else{
        alert('You discarded the changes!');
      }
    } 
  </script>
```

The `updateAddress()` function its on my `app-component.ts` file. I would like to know how I could call a typescript function from a javascript function without getting `Uncaught ReferenceError`. Thank you.

Comment: Why is his click event not bound and handled within typescript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling properly TypeScript code from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26427722/calling-properly-typescript-code-from-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, as long as your typescript is correctly compiled in Javascript, and your function is exported in the global scope.

But I have to say, it seems wrong to do that in so many way. First exposing something in the global scope is never a good idea. Second, I don't see why you would want to wrote pure javascript scripts in an Angular application.

But yes, technically, it's possible to do what you want, event though I strongly advise against it.

Hope that helps

Comment: It's hard to give a helpful answer to subpar question. This one is more like verbose comment rather than answer. It doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can you give and advise on how should I do it?!

Answer (score 0):

Think you'll find the answer here.

[Uncaught ReferenceError: <function> is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41326567/uncaught-referenceerror-function-is-not-defined-at-htmlbuttonelement-onclick)

Short answer is you need to add it to global scope. E.g add it to index.html and it should fire. But I recommend that you add it to your .ts-file and rewrite the function